# java regex merging

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to merge these two conditions:

```
^(?:(?=[\W])[@#!$%])+$
```

and

```
(?=^.{8,25}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

where instead of accepting all special characters, I want to restrict them to accept only [@#!$%].

Comment: Your first regex is a longer way to say `^[@#!$%]+$` and your second seems to express this `^(?=.{8,25}$)(?=\D*\d)(?=[^\w]*\W)(?![^.]*\.)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$`. Putting all together: `^(?=.{8,25}$)(?=\D*\d)(?=[^\w]*\W)(?![^.]*\.)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$|^[@#!$%]+$`

Comment: It's  not as expected.
Welcome123*@        should not accept and
Welcome123@         should

Comment: So add more sample inputs and expected outputs where regex should match or not.

Comment: should contain (in any order) - number, uppercase , lower case, and special char (only [@#!$%] ) if other than this special char present , string should get rejected

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your merging should mean a different match on second regex. If that's right this would validate those strings:

```
^(?=[\w@#!$%]{8,25}$)(?=\w*[@#!$%])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

- `(?=[\w@#!$%]{8,25}$)` Checks if input string contains these chars only

This allows underscores as it is matched by `\w` if you want to exclude them from match do this:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9@#!$%]{8,25}$)(?=\w*[@#!$%])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zBLAdz/3)

Comment: sorry but it is accepting 'TESTstring123' which is wrong

Comment: ^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9@#!$%]{8,25}$)(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#!$%]).*$

this might work

Comment: Are you forcing at least an occurrence of `[@#!$%]` characters?

Comment: can you explain (?=\D*\d) , why \D

Comment: `\D*` means any non-digit characters. I used `\D` to prevent any further backtracks. It's a performance-wise step. If this answer was helpful you may want to upvote it (using up-arrow at left) and accept it (using check mark at left side of answer) if it provides an answer to your question. Thank you @user9471000